No 2-design without entanglement?
Is it true that $\mathbf{U}(2)^{\otimes n}$ forms a 1-design (or at most) for all $n \geq 2$? I would greatly appreciate a reference.

For a distribution $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathrm{U}(2^n)$ we can define the $t$-th frame potential
$$\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{D}^{(t)} = \operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{U,V \sim \mathcal{D}} |\mathrm{tr}(U^\dagger V)|^{2t}.$$
If $\mathcal{D}$ is a group, then this simplifies to $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{D}^{(t)} = \operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}_{U \sim \mathcal{D}} |\mathrm{tr}(U)|^{2t}$. It holds that $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{D}^{(t)} \geq \mathcal{F}_{\mathrm{U}(2^n)}^{(t)}$, with equality if and only if $\mathcal{D}$ is a unitary $t$-design.
Let us take $\mathcal{D} = \mathrm{U}(2)^{\otimes n}$ and $t = 2$. Using the fact that $\mathrm{tr}(A \otimes B) = \mathrm{tr}(A) \, \mathrm{tr}(B)$, we get
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{D}}^{(2)} &= \int_{\mathrm{U}(2)^{\otimes n}} dU_1 \cdots dU_n \, |\mathrm{tr}(U_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes U_n)|^4\\
&= \prod_{j=1}^n \int_{\mathrm{U}(2)} dU_j \, |\mathrm{tr}(U_j)|^4\\
&= \left( \mathcal{F}_{\mathrm{U}(2)}^{(2)} \right)^n.
\end{align*}$$
The $t$-th frame potential for $\mathrm{U}(d)$ is $t!$ whenever $t \leq d$, so
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{D}}^{(2)} &= 2^n,\\
\mathcal{F}_{\mathrm{U}(2^n)}^{(2)} &= 2,
\end{align*}$$
and hence $\mathcal{D}$ is not a 2-design. In contrast, observe that $\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{D}}^{(1)} = 1 = \mathcal{F}_{\mathrm{U}(2^n)}^{(1)}$, so it is indeed always a 1-design.
For a reference, see the classic paper by Gross, Audenaert, and Eisert.
